# R Studio Quarto Markdown Error - OS Error 2 - "The system cannot find the file specified" - after update to R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, quarto

I recently updated R and R Studio, and started getting an error message on Quarto Markdown documents, rendering to HTML. This is happening on brand-new "test" documents as well as actual HTML reports. I have uninstalled and re-installed R Studio and Quarto and I am still getting the error.

I also tried to follow the advice in this post: https://community.rstudio.com/t/render-with-quarto-error/134403/6
But it's over my head.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR: NotFound: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2), remove 'test_files\mediabag'

NotFound: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2), remove 'test_files\mediabag'
    at Object.removeSync (deno:runtime/js/30_fs.js:157:9)
    at removeIfEmptyDir (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:5701:18)
    at renderCleanup (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:80576:5)
    at file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:81110:46
    at withTiming (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:19624:25)
    at Object.complete (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:81110:13)
    at async Object.onPostProcess (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:86677:36)
    at async renderFiles (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:86648:13)
    at async render (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:90679:21)
    at async renderForPreview (file:///C:/PROGRA~1/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:102413:26)
```

My html document still renders at the end, but it is not self-contained as I had requested in the header.

Here's my R session info:
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

RStudio version:
2023.06.0 Build 421

I'm lost - thank you in advance for your help!